# django: permission to add certain query parameter in certain view

Tags: django

I've been reading docs no django's authentication framework and plugins, and here's what I'm trying to achieve:

A registered user is granted access to a certain url, say, `www.domain.com/sales-overview/`, he can view all he want, but he can't access `www.domain.com/sales-overview/?city=newyork`, because whatever reasons.

Now how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to implement this content access logic within your view's function. The function `has_perms` may come handy. More on [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends).

Also, if you need to implement per object permissions, take a look at [Django Guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian).

Answer (score 0):

In your view you can check if user has proper rights. If everything is OK, you just render the page. If user has no rights, return `HttpResponseForbidden()`.